# Newly created Site in SXA, publishing the full site gives error

Tags: sxa, publishing

When publishing the complete website, I am getting error. I have tried to find the solution but found so far that the configs might be corrupted. I have checked:

- Configurations are all set.
- The Sitecore solution works fine, though (something related to SXA might be causing the issue.

I am using Sitecore 9.0 update 1 and SXA 1.7.

Here is the log:

> Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:moving' event.
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
>      at Sitecore.Events.Event.DataEngine_MovingItem(Object sender, ExecutingEventArgs`1 e)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseExecuting(Boolean& cancelled)
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.CanExecute()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
>      at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.MoveItem(Item item, Item destination, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.MoveItems.MoveTargetItem(Item targetItem, ID destinationId, PublishItemContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.MoveItems.ProcessItem(Item sourceItem, Item targetItem, PublishItemContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.MoveItems.Process(PublishItemContext context)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
>      at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
>      at (Object , Object[] )
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()
>      at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a (now) known bug in SXA 1.7 when publishing an item that has been moved. I just tested the fix and it works. You can find it here: https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.13144/releases/tag/1.7.0.0

This handler is causing the problems: `<handler type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.EventHandlers.VirtualMediaFolderValidator, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite">`. We removed it to be able to publish, but the fix is a better solution.

Comment: worked like a charm. thx @gatogordo